# "TypeError: this.pineconeIndex.namespace is not a function"

Tags: next.js, langchain, pinecone

In my NextJS 14 project, I am trying to use Pinecone to vectorize and index a given PDF file and push it to a Pinecone database. This is how I’m doing it:

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */

import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai"
import { PineconeStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone"
import getPineconeClient from "@/lib/pinecone"

async function streamToArrayBuffer(stream: ReadableStream) {
  return new Uint8Array(await new Response(stream).arrayBuffer())
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const data = await request.body

  if (!data) return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
  const arrayBuffer = await streamToArrayBuffer(data)
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
  const loader = new PDFLoader(blob)
  const pageLevelDocs = await loader.load()
  const pagesAmt = pageLevelDocs.length

  // Vectorize and index document
  const pinecone = await getPineconeClient()
  const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index("poco")
  const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
    openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  })
  await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(pageLevelDocs, embeddings, {
    pineconeIndex,
    namespace: "pdf",
  })

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true, pages: pagesAmt })
}
```

My Pinecone configuration (`pinecone.ts`) looks like this:

```
import { PineconeClient } from "@pinecone-database/pinecone"

const getPineconeClient = async () => {
  const client = new PineconeClient()

  await client.init({
    apiKey: process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY!,
    environment: process.env.PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT as string,
  })

  return client
}
export default getPineconeClient
```

This should work fine but the server is still throwing a **type error** saying:

> this.pineconeIndex.namespace is not a function

I also tried importing PineconeStore from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/pinecone" instead of "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone" but the error persisted.